# How to change the admin password with Etherpad Lite that runs inside a docker container?

Tags: docker, etherpad

I have Etherpad running inside a docker container.

I set up the docker with:

```
docker run -d --name=etherpad --restart=always --network=host \
-e ADMIN_PASSWORD=pw12345 \
-e DB_TYPE=postgres \
-e DB_USER=postgres \
-e DB_PASS=pw12345 \
-e DB_NAME=etherpad \
-e DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 \
etherpad/etherpad
```

When opening the website under `/admin/` I need to login accordingly:

[image: admin login popup]

Now I would like to change the admin password `pw12345` to a safer password.

I can open the website under `/admin/settings` and find the content of `settings.json` there. One line says `"password": "${ADMIN_PASSWORD:null}",` but as I understand, this is the user management of Etherpad itself.

I assume the "login admin" password is set somewhere else.

How to change the admin password?

By the way, this changes the root password of the running docker container (but not the login prompt):

> docker exec -itu 0 etherpad passwd

Then assign the new password. But this docker password is not the password for the Etherpad admin login.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the solution is to change the line `"password": "${ADMIN_PASSWORD:null}",` inside the `admin/settings` to something like:

```
"password": "thenewrandompassword",
is_admin": true
```

This password is valid for the admin login on the website.